# Error on installing jdk 7 on solaris 5.8 - # Error: libjvm.so: symbol __fmodf: referenced symbol not found

Tags: java, linux, oracle, oracle8

I got the following error when installing the JDK7 (u71) on the Solaris 5.8.

The error when I try to run java -version is:

```
Error: failed /opt/jdk7/jdk1.7.0_71/jre/lib/sparcv9/server/libjvm.so, because ld.so.1: java: fatal: relocation error: file /opt/jdk7/jdk1.7.0_71/jre/lib/sparcv9/server/libjvm.so: symbol __fmodf: referenced symbol not found
```

Here is some information of my server:

```
#uname -a
SunOS hostname 5.8 Generic_117350-62 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V240

# isainfo -v
64-bit sparcv9 applications
32-bit sparc applications
```

I use the installation guide here:

```
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/solaris/solaris-jdk.html
(section "Installation of Oracle Solaris Archive Binaries (.tar.gz)")
```

I also downloaded:

```
jdk-7u71-solaris-sparc.tar.gz
jdk-7u71-solaris-sparcv9.tar.gz
```

#### I notice that on Sun 5.10, I use the same way and the JDK work normally.

Does any one had the same issue? Many thanks to you.

**Finally:** I decide to switch to a Linux box to use JDK7. Thanks all for your supports.

Comment: Solaris 8 has been unsupported since 2009 (https://blogs.oracle.com/jimmo/entry/solaris_8_end_of_service). I wouldn't be too surprised by current software not working with it.

Comment: [Oracle JDK 7 and JRE 7 Certified System Configurations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/config-417990.html) - requires Solaris 10 Update 9.